# remove virtual keyword from xamarin java binding

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently I'm trying to convert a jar file to dll with Xamarin Java Binding project.

Here is the java code 
     `public int compareTo(java.lang.object paramPGAbsEffect)`

which becomes
    `public virtual unsafe int CompareTo (object p0)`
in my c# code.
I want to just remove the virtual keyword, because it is not there in Java file.

I tried
    `... /method[@name='compareTo']" name="virtual">false`
but this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

All Java functions are virtual by default, unless you use final keyword. Thus, the tool just does its job and you should learn more about both Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `final` to `true` in the `Metadata.xml` mapping:

```
<attr 
   path="/api/package[@name='your.package.here']/class[@name='YourClass.InnerClass']/method[@name='methodName']" 
   name="final">true</attr>
```

This effectively removes the `virtual` keyword from the method signature, and doesn't add the `final` keyword either. Strange behavior, but it works.